# Semicharacters on groups

Tags: gr.group-theory

I think, this must be simple, but apparently, I don't have enough intuition, so excuse me. The following construction is useful in the [holomorphic duality theory for complex Lie Groups](https://arxiv.org/abs/0806.3205):

Let $G$ be an arbitrary group. A function $s:G\to [1,+\infty)$ is called a *semicharacter* on $G$, if
$$
s(x\cdot y)\le s(x)\cdot s(y),\qquad x,y\in G.
$$
Question:

> is it true that for any group $G$, for any its subgroup $H\subseteq G$ and for any semicharacter $c:H\to [1,+\infty)$ there is a semicharacter $s:G\to [1,+\infty)$ that majorates $c$ on $H$:
> $$
> c(x)\le s(x),\qquad x\in H
> $$
> ?

Comment: I guess this is usually called "submultiplicative".

Comment: Yes, this can be called "a submultiplicative function".

Comment: No it's not true in general. On $\mathbf{Z}$, consider the function $n\mapsto 2^{|n|}$. If $\mathbf{Z}$ is embedded in the center of the Heisenberg group (or in any group where it's distorted), every subadditive function on the Heisenberg is $\le C\sqrt{|n|}$ on $\mathbf{Z}$, hence every submultiplciative function on $\mathbf{Z}$ extending to a submultiplicative function is $\le\exp( C\sqrt{|n|})$ for some $C>0$. The usual keyword is "distortion".

Comment: YCor, and why is each subadditive function on the Heisenberg group $\le C\sqrt{|n|}$ on $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Hint: $[e_{12}^n,e_{23}^n]=e_{13}^{n^2}$, where $e_{ij}=I_3+E_{ij}$.

Comment: @YCor I want to mention this example in my text. How can I refer to you?

Comment: This is classical in geometric group theory, so I don't need attribution. Just happy to help here!

Comment: OK, thank you, YCor!